How to create a wrapper over gio.OutputStream to send a chunked transfer encoding stream on Rust
I want to create a chunked transfer encoding class that inheritance from OutputStream and delegates to another OutputStream, something as follows: ChunkedOutputStream(inner = OutputStream) , where ChunkedOutputStream implements OutputStream, and ChunkedOutputStream methods might delegate to the inner OutputStream
What I have tried is something like:
use gio::prelude::*;
use gio::{glib, OutputStream};
use glib::subclass::prelude::*;
use glib::translate::*;
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct ChunkedOutputStream {
    inner: Rc<RefCell<gio::OutputStream>>,
}

impl ChunkedOutputStream {
    pub fn new(inner: gio::OutputStream) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: Rc::new(RefCell::new(inner)),
        }
    }

    fn write_chunk(&self, chunk: &[u8]) -> Result<usize, io::Error> {
        let mut inner = self.inner.borrow_mut();

        // Write the chunk size in hex followed by CRLF
        let chunk_size = format!("{:X}\r\n", chunk.len());
        inner.write_all(chunk_size.as_bytes(), None).unwrap();

        // Write the actual chunk data
        inner.write_all(chunk, None).unwrap();

        // Write a CRLF after the chunk data
        inner.write_all(b"\r\n", None).unwrap();

        Ok(chunk.len())
    }

    fn write_final_chunk(&self) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        let mut inner = self.inner.borrow_mut();

        // Write the final chunk (0) to signal end of stream
        inner.write_all(b"0\r\n\r\n", None).unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl OutputStreamExt for ChunkedOutputStream {
    fn write(&self, buffer: &[u8], _cancellable: Option<&gio::Cancellable>) -> Result<usize, glib::Error> {
        // Implement the chunked writing
        match self.write_chunk(buffer) {
            Ok(len) => Ok(len),
            Err(err) => Err(glib::Error::new(gio::IOErrorEnum::Failed, &err.to_string())),
        }
    }

    fn close(&self, _cancellable: Option<&gio::Cancellable>) -> Result<(), glib::Error> {
        // Write the final chunk to indicate the end of the transfer
        match self.write_final_chunk() {
            Ok(()) => Ok(()),
            Err(err) => Err(glib::Error::new(gio::IOErrorEnum::Failed, &err.to_string())),
        }
    }
}

However, the impl OutputStreamExt for ChunkedOutputStream section doesn't compile as it requires to implement a lot of supertraits. When I accept the suggestion from RustRover IDE, it creates a ton of implementations that doesn't compile. The following is the compile error using cargo test:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ObjectRef: From<ChunkedOutputStream>` is not satisfied
  --> src/chunked_output_stream.rs:51:26
   |
51 | impl OutputStreamExt for ChunkedOutputStream {
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<ChunkedOutputStream>` is not implemented for `ObjectRef`, which is required by `ChunkedOutputStream: IsA<OutputStream>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `OutputStream: From<ChunkedOutputStream>` is not satisfied
  --> src/chunked_output_stream.rs:51:26
   |
51 | impl OutputStreamExt for ChunkedOutputStream {
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<ChunkedOutputStream>` is not implemented for `OutputStream`, which is required by `ChunkedOutputStream: IsA<OutputStream>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `ChunkedOutputStream: IsA<OutputStream>` is not satisfied
  --> src/chunked_output_stream.rs:51:26
   |
51 | impl OutputStreamExt for ChunkedOutputStream {
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `IsA<OutputStream>` is not implemented for `ChunkedOutputStream`

I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this wrapper or if there is an already created implementation for the chunked transfer encoding algorithm.

This is the final code, probably a naive implementation but it is working:
use gio::prelude::*;
use gio::{glib, Cancellable, OutputStream};
use glib::subclass::prelude::*;
use glib::translate::*;

mod imp {
    use super::*;
    use gio::glib::Error;
    use gio::subclass::prelude::OutputStreamImpl;
    use gio::IOErrorEnum::NotFound;
    use std::cell::RefCell;

    #[derive(Default)]
    pub struct ChunkedOutputStream {
        pub(super) inner: RefCell<Option<OutputStream>>,
    }

    #[glib::object_subclass]
    impl ObjectSubclass for ChunkedOutputStream {
        const NAME: &'static str = "ChunkedOutputStream";
        type Type = super::ChunkedOutputStream;
        type ParentType = OutputStream;
    }

    impl ObjectImpl for ChunkedOutputStream {}

    impl OutputStreamImpl for ChunkedOutputStream {
        fn write(
            &self,
            chunk: &[u8],
            _cancellable: Option<&Cancellable>,
        ) -> Result<usize, Error> {
            if let Some(ref mut stream) = *self.inner.borrow_mut() {
                // Write the chunk size in hex followed by CRLF
                let chunk_size = format!("{:X}\r\n", chunk.len());
                stream.write_all(chunk_size.as_bytes(), None::<&Cancellable>).unwrap();

                // Write the actual chunk data
                stream.write_all(chunk, None::<&Cancellable>).unwrap();

                // Write a CRLF after the chunk data
                stream.write_all(b"\r\n", None::<&Cancellable>).unwrap();

                Ok(chunk.len())
            } else {
                Err(Error::new(NotFound, "No output stream available"))
            }
        }

        fn close(&self, cancellable: Option<&Cancellable>) -> Result<(), Error> {
            if let Some(ref mut stream) = *self.inner.borrow_mut() {
                // Write the final chunk (0) to signal end of stream
                stream.write_all(b"0\r\n\r\n", None::<&Cancellable>).unwrap();
                stream.close(None::<&Cancellable>).unwrap();

                Ok(())
            } else {
                Err(Error::new(NotFound, "No output stream available"))
            }
        }
    }
    unsafe impl Send for ChunkedOutputStream {}
}

glib::wrapper! {
        pub struct ChunkedOutputStream(ObjectSubclass<imp::ChunkedOutputStream>)
            @extends OutputStream;
}

impl ChunkedOutputStream {
    pub fn new(output_stream: OutputStream) -> ChunkedOutputStream {
        let stream = glib::Object::new::<ChunkedOutputStream>();

        *stream.imp().inner.borrow_mut() = Some(output_stream);
        stream
    }
}

To create the wrapper, you use ChunkedOutputStream::new(output_stream)
